# How to return a Date format when I use setDate()

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I assigned the weekEnd as the current end of the week like this

```
this.weekEnd = new Date(this.currentDate.setDate(end));
```

Next, what I want is to give a new value to the weekEnd which is the weekEnd + 7 days. I've done it like below but I can't assign the new value to the weekEnd because the right side returns a Number and not date.

```
this.weekEnd = this.weekEnd.setDate(this.weekEnd.getDate() + 7);
```

If you guys have any idea how I can do it I would appreciate it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What stands for this currentDate and end ? can you show the full code ¿?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `.setDate()` method without the assignment:

```
this.weekEnd.setDate(this.weekEnd.getDate() + 7);
```

`.setDate()` does two things:

1. It changes the current Date object to the new date.
2. Returns the number of milliseconds of that new date since 1 Jan 1970.

In your code you assigned this number to the variable that would have held the correct date anyway.

Comment: Of course, you are right! Thanks for mentioning it. Both are so incredibly short that I mixed them up. :D. Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will return 15th Jun and 21st June. If you remove +1 then it will start from sunday. To start from monday you have to add 1.

```
let current = new Date;
let firstday = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate() - current.getDay()+1));
let lastday = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate() - current.getDay()+7));
```